# How to completely uninstall portainer?

Tags: docker, portainer

Feeling very frustrated. I installed Portainer on a NUC at home (using [these simple instructions](https://docs.portainer.io/start/install/server/docker/linux)). Messed up a bit, and now want to start from scratch.

Now whatever I try, Portainer is persistent and doesn't go away.

- I removed the container. `sudo docker ps -a` shows nothing. Portainer still runs after reboot.
- I removed the `portainer_data` volume. Still running (now doesn't recognize my password - can't go into the UI).
- I even tried `netstat -tulpn | grep 9443` and killed the two processes accessing the port (`docker-proxy`), still the UI runs fine!!

How do I get rid or Portainer?!?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
docker container rm -f portainer
```

`rm` will remove a container, `-f` will force stop it before removing it.

You can list all your containers with

```
docker container ls
```